# How can i send a DM message to someone just by mentioning his name in on_message in discord.py

Tags: discord, python-3.7, discord.py

I want the bot to send a DM message to the user whose name is in the message content, here is the code:

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        for user in People:  # People list includes all members' names in the server
            if f'{user}' in message.content:
                await message.user.send("Hi")
            else:
                pass
```

I know that the problem is in `await message.user.send("Hi")` but all I want is when i say in my msg (for example) "Hello Ahmed" the bot should send a DM message to ahmed saying "Hi"

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to iterate everybody's name in the guild. [`discord.Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message) has attribute [`mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.mentions). It returns a list of member that mentioned in the message. So you can just iterate that list.

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    for member in message.mentions:
        await member.send('Hi')
```