# How do I dm someone with discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want the bot to message me when it reboots. I can't seem to figure it out.

I tried a bunch of stuff and I get the error: "user is a required argument that is missing."

```
@client.command()
async def DM(ctx, *, user:discord.Member):
    await user.send('The Bot Is online')
```

Here I tried doing it with a command, just to see if it works and got the same error.

Comment: did u ping the user to pass his name as parameter to the function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i send a DM message to someone just by mentioning his name in on\_message in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64361969/how-can-i-send-a-dm-message-to-someone-just-by-mentioning-his-name-in-on-message)

Answer (score 3):

Use `on_ready` event:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    user = client.get_user(user_id)  # specify user_id here
    await user.send("The bot is online!")
```